# Dynamic renderURL within aui-datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2-ce-ga4, attempting to embed custom renderURL's within a aui-datatable column.  The following code works, except when I attempt invoking the following line of code from within a column formatter function:

```
var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
```

There is no error code generated in the Eclipse Console when invoking this code (as I am launching Liferay from within Eclispe).  All I can tell you is that when I comment out the above line, I get a properly generated DataTable, but after uncommenting the line, the DataTable simply does not render.

The full page of code is as follows

```
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>

<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<%
    JSONArray involvedParties = (JSONArray) renderRequest.getAttribute("involvedPartyDetails");
%>

<aui:script>
    YUI().use('aui-datatable', 'datatable-sort', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(Y) {

        var columns = [ {
            label : 'Involved Party Name',
            key : 'name',
            formatter : function(o) {
                // var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
                return '<a href="http://www.cnn.com/">' + o.data.name + '</a>';
            },
            allowHTML : true,
            sortable : true
        } ];

        var data = <%=involvedParties%>
        var dataTable = new Y.DataTable({
            columns : columns,
            data : data,
            scrollable : "y",
            height : "500px"
        }).render('#myDataTable');
    });
</aui:script>

<div id="myDataTable"></div>
```

My liferay-portlet.xml is given as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>involved-party-list</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>
            /js/main.js
        </footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>
            involved-party-list-portlet
        </css-class-wrapper>
        <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Any suggestions on how to build a dynamic renderURL for each row in the data table is appreciated.

As a side note, I have tried replacing YUI() with AUI(), but that also results in the data table not being generated within the browser.  Comments on the benefits of using AUI vs YUI would also be appreciated.

Comment: Also discussed here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/63339849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving part of the answer yourself - however, there's something more to it: `<aui:script>` already makes AUI available. You can just replace your lines

```
<aui:script>
    YUI().use('aui-datatable', 'datatable-sort', 'liferay-portlet-url', function(Y) {
```

with

```
<aui:script use="aui-datatable,datatable-sort,liferay-portlet-url">
```

and use AUI as A in the block that this opens. No need for an additional YUI or AUI block within this tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Chrome's "Developer Tools Console" to view output, and was getting the following error message:

```
yui: NOT loaded: liferay-portlet-url
```

It seems I must use AUI() instead of YUI() to leverage Liferay extensions.